# Avoid warning when two structs include each other

Tags: c, structure

I'm trying to implement a thread pooling system in my application. I would love that each thread has a pointer to the thread pooling structure I'm using. So, basically I've two structure similar to what follows:

```
typedef struct thread_pool {
    /* some fields here */
    single_thread **tds;
} thread_pool_t;

typedef struct single_thread {
    /* some fields here */
    thread_pool_t *tp;
} single_thread_t;
```

Independently of the order of declaration, the compiler will give an error. I solved declaring the second structure before the first one, but declaring it empty. Now I don't get any errors, but I always get the following warning:

```
serv_inc/thrhandler.h:23:16: warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]
```

Is there any way to avoid this warning and achieve the same result? Am I doing it wrong and is there a more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: This can never work. There is no `struct` keyword and there should be a forward declaration. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
typedef struct thread_pool thread_pool_t;
typedef struct single_thread single_thread_t;

struct thread_pool
{
    single_thread_t **tds;
};

struct single_thread
{
    thread_pool_t *tp;
};
```